# Yosemite: How to change the index of a specific monitor while using a set of multiple monitors?

Tags: macos, display, window-manager

Say you use a MacBook Pro (MBP) and you have a specific monitor setup of at least two external monitors. As the main desktop you use the internal monitor of the MacBook Pro. This monitor setup you use at different locations and different monitor models.

If you disconnect your MBP from the external monitors and reconnect them, the *window positions are restored*. After changing the workplace and the monitor models, the window positions are **not properly restored** - sometimes they are *mixed up*, sometimes they are *reversed*.

Obviously Yosemite is not able to restore monitor positions correctly when monitor models have changed. But it stores the display arrangement correctly, so the monitors are known by Yosemite and identified.

**How to change and save the indices of the known displays permanently?**

A preferred solution would be one, where no third-party software has to be purchased.

Comment: This is a touch nut to crack. I have similar issues when mixing a retina screen with a non-retina screen as the saved window positions are not robust to handle the changes in geometry. I've given up on solving this and instead use a tool called Divvy to quickly reimpose order when things get messed up. https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/divvy-window-manager/id413857545?mt=12 The benefit is I have a tool to automate sizing of new windows as well as those that get "adjusted" by the OS.